# How can I preserve missing cells in a downloaded data file?

Tags: python, r, data-cleaning

I have a crappy dataset which I got from https://cdsarc.cds.unistra.fr/viz-bin/cat/J/MNRAS/495/1706#/browse, and I'm trying to clean it up using Python and R. The HTML file looks like [this](https://cdsarc.cds.unistra.fr/viz-bin/nph-Cat/html?J/MNRAS/495/1706/subaru.dat.gz):
[image]
but when I download the file, it contains extra spaces as padding, as well as where there is missing data. This means that I can't use Python's `.replace` method to change the spaces to `NA`s. After downloading the original file, I replace the spaces with commas using this script:

```
with open("./emerlin_vla_subaru/subaru.dat", 'r') as f:
    a=f.readlines()

with open("./emerlin_vla_subaru/subaru_fixed.dat" ,"w+") as f:
    for i in range(len(a)):
        c=a[i].split()
        f.write(",".join(c))
        f.write("\n")
```

but this method deletes the missing cells and shifts the data to the left to fill the blanks. I tried using R, but it doesn't realize that there are those blank cells in the middle of the data. Does anyone know how I can clean up the data, or find an already tidied version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, you can `install.packages("rvest")` and use

```
x <- (rvest::read_html("subaru.dat.gz") |> rvest::html_table())[[1L]]
```

to get the data into a dataframe without loss. The only thing you need is RAM since R is quite a RAM-intensive language, and your HTML file is very large. It takes about 5 mins to read the data into memory. The whole process peaked at slightly more than 14 GiB memory usage on my laptop.

The output should look like this

```
> x
# A tibble: 376,380 x 28
   `RAdeg DEdegdeg ~ `Bmag (e)mag`  `Vmag (e)mag`  `rmag (e)mag`  `imag (e)mag` `zmag (e)mag` `ymag (e)mag` `[3.6] (e)mag`
   <chr>             <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         
 1 157.7550584  67.~ 21.6219      ~ 24.0         ~ 23.3316      ~ 22.0066     ~ 21.115      ~ ""            "19.87723732 ~
 2 157.7448037  67.~ 25.0246      ~ 23.9475      ~ 22.9581      ~ 22.2232     ~ 22.003      ~ ""            ""            
 3 157.7565074  67.~ 24.7904      ~ 25.4817      ~ 24.5512      ~ 23.5114     ~ 24.6046     ~ ""            ""            
 4 157.7241218  67.~ 25.1506      ~ 24.0261      ~ 22.7778      ~ 21.7253     ~ 21.2324     ~ "23.87630082~ "20.19021606 ~
 5 157.7430948  67.~ 24.0397      ~ 23.6024      ~ 22.9016      ~ 22.2357     ~ 22.0235     ~ ""            ""            
 6 157.7508459  67.~ 25.3215      ~ 25.3467      ~ 24.385       ~ 24.7648     ~ 24.5042     ~ ""            ""            
 7 157.728751   67.~ 23.7913      ~ 23.5786      ~ 22.4722      ~ 22.05       ~ 21.7701     ~ ""            ""            
 8 157.7336379  67.~ 25.5835      ~ 23.5972      ~ 22.0607      ~ 20.7663     ~ 20.3327     ~ ""            "19.24077034 ~
 9 157.7610664  67.~ 25.2398      ~ 24.6624      ~ 24.3885      ~ 24.1111     ~ 23.2762     ~ ""            ""            
10 157.7563166  67.~ 23.1946      ~ 28.0006      ~ 32.30285645  ~ 24.701      ~ 23.2054     ~ ""            ""            
# ... with 376,370 more rows, and 20 more variables: [4.5] (e)mag <chr>, Id--- <dbl>, za--- <dbl>, chiza--- <dbl>,
#   (e) (E) <chr>, (e) (E) <chr>, Nfilt--- <dbl>, e1--- <dbl>, e2--- <dbl>, Radpix <dbl>, RadRatio--- <dbl>,
#   BulgeA--- <dbl>, DiscA--- <dbl>, BulgeIndex--- <dbl>, DiscIndex--- <dbl>, BulgeFlux--- <dbl>, DiscFlux--- <dbl>,
#   FluxRatio--- <dbl>, snr--- <dbl>, SourceId--- <chr>
```

Performance measurement

```
> system.time(x <- (rvest::read_html("subaru.dat.gz") |> rvest::html_table())[[1L]])
   user  system elapsed 
 288.75    2.72  291.62
```

Comment: I get `Error: unexpected '>' in "sub <- (rvest::read_html("subaru.dat.gz") |>"`

Comment: Oh, then you are probably not running the latest version of R since the native pipe operator `|>` was only introduced in 4.1.0. You can change that line of code to `rvest::html_table(rvest::read_html("subaru.dat.gz"))[[1L]]` @Jim421616

Comment: Changing that leads to `Error in rvest::html_table(rvest::read_html("subaru.dat.gz"))[[1L]] : 
  subscript out of bounds`

Comment: Did you change the file path to the correct one? `rvest::read_html("subaru.dat.gz")` assumes there is a file named "subaru.dat.gz" in the current working directory. @Jim421616

Comment: Yes, they're all in the same folder, and I've set the current working directory to be that same folder. I've also tried it with the unzipped file.

Comment: In this case, you may try to do it step by step. 1) `x <- rvest::read_html("subaru.dat.gz")`. See if it is running correctly. 2) `y <- rvest::html_table(x)`. See if anything is returned. My best guess is that you are using a different version of `rvest` or your file is corrupted. I downloaded that file following your second link using `download.file("https://cdsarc.cds.unistra.fr/viz-bin/nph-Cat/html?J/MNRAS/495/1706/subaru.dat.gz", "subaru.dat.gz")`. The size of that file is 489961Kb. @Jim421616

Comment: Ok, I think that's got it, thanks. How can I convert the tibble into a dataframe and save it as a csv?

Comment: @Jim421616 tibble is a subclass of a dataframe. You can use whatever method you want to apply to dataframes to it. For example, `reader::write_csv`, `write.csv` or `data.table::fwrite` all should work.

Comment: I've asked a follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70674413/dataframe-extracted-from-downloaded-html-file-contains-floats-separated-by-space